Restriction of the local Artin map on the valuation ring of a local field
Let $F$ be a local field, in particular a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for some prime $p$ and let $Art_{L}: L^\times \to Gal(F^{ab}/F)$ be its local Artin map. We know that if $L/F$ is a finite unramified extension and $\pi$ is an uniformizer for the ring $\mathcal{O}_F$ then $Art_F(\pi)_{|L}=\Phi_{L/F}$ where $\Phi_{L/F}$ is Frobenius for the extension $L/F$. Moreover if $L/F$ is an abelian extension we have the isomorphism $Art_{L/F}:F^\times/N_{L/K}(L^\times) \to Gal(L/F)$ and a surjective version of this map $Art_{L/F}:F^\times \to Gal(L/F)$.
I am trying to prove that the second version of $Art_{L/F}$ maps $\mathcal{O}_F$ to $Gal(L/F^{nr}\cap L)$. My idea is:
Since $Art_{L/F}$ is surjective, it is enough to prove that
\begin{equation*}
        Art_{L/F}^{-1}(Gal(L/F^{nr} \cap L))=\mathcal{O}_F^\times.
    \end{equation*}
In order to prove it, take $a\in F^\times$. Then
\begin{equation*}
        a=\pi^{val(a)}x
    \end{equation*}
with $x$ in $\mathcal{O}_F^\times$, and hence
\begin{equation*}
        Art_{L/F}(a)_{|F^{nr} \cap L}=\Phi_{F^{nr} \cap L/F}^{val(a)}Art_{L/F}(x)_{|F^{nr} \cap L}=\Phi_{F^{nr} \cap L/F}^{val(a)}.
    \end{equation*}
And hence
\begin{equation*}
        Art_{L/F}(a)_{|F^{nr} \cap L}=Id \iff val(a)=0 \iff a \in \mathcal{O}_F^\times.
    \end{equation*}
In other word, $Art_{L/F}(a)_{|L}$ is in $Gal(L/F^{nr} \cap L)$ if, and only if, $a$ is in $\mathcal{O}_F^\times$.
The problem I am stack on is
\begin{equation} \Phi_{F^{nr} \cap L/F}^{val(a)}Art_{L/F}(x)_{|F^{nr} \cap L}=\Phi_{F^{nr} \cap L/F}^{val(a)}
\end{equation}
I am sure enough of it, but I don't find a solution.
